# Laravel 4 When i retrieve info from database into input text, 1 extra space is added

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I am doing a form where the user can update his information. The form shows several inputs and the info retrieved from the database is displayed inside them.
I have noticed that, when the info is displayed, one extra space is added. For example, if i retrieve a date '1965-08-29', then in the form i notice that an extra space is added at the end: '1965-08-29 '.

This is happening in all inputs causing validation fails.

Here is a sample code about how i retrieve the data inside the controller:

```
$id_user=Auth::user()->id;
    $usuario=User::find($id_user);
    if(isset($usuario->nombre_pila)){$nombrepila=$usuario->nombre_pila;}else{$nombrepila='';}
    if(isset($usuario->ap_paterno)){$ap_paterno=$usuario->ap_paterno;}else{$ap_paterno='';}
    if(isset($usuario->ap_materno)){$ap_materno=$usuario->ap_materno;}else{$ap_materno='';}
```

Here is how i send these data to the view:

```
return View::make('profile.edit',array('id_user'=>$id_user, 'nombrepila'=>$nombrepila, 'ap_paterno'=>$ap_paterno,'ap_materno'=>$ap_materno));
```

Here are some examples of the inputs in the view:

```
    <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('nombre_pila')) has-error @endif"><!--Nombre de pila-->
        <label for="nombre_pila" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre(s) de pila:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_pila" name="nombre_pila" maxlength="45" value="@if(isset($nombrepila)){{$nombrepila}} @endif">
        </div>    
    @if($errors->has('nombre_pila'))
        {{$errors->first('nombre_pila')}}
    @endif
    </div><!-- ----------fin nombre de pila ------------ -->

    <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('ap_paterno')) has-error @endif"><!--apellido paterno-->
        <label for="ap_paterno" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Apellido paterno:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ap_paterno" name="ap_paterno" maxlength="45" value="@if(isset($ap_paterno)){{$ap_paterno}} @endif">
        </div>
    @if($errors->has('ap_paterno'))
        {{$errors->first('ap_paterno')}}
    @endif    
    </div><!-- ----------fin de apellido paterno ------------ -->
```

I am using bootstrap 3 forms (i don't know whether this has to do with the problem or not)

It could be that i should use something like the `rtrim()` function. But if someone out there could explain me why this is happening or what i am missing to do, i'll appreciate it.

Comment: It's probably the space before your `@endif`s in the view

Comment: @lukasgeiter Yeah!!! That did the trick!

Comment: No problem pathros ;)

Comment: I answered the question now, so it is clear that the issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space before your `@endif`s. To fix that either do

```
value="@if(isset($ap_paterno)){{$ap_paterno}}@endif"
```

or (a bit nicer in my opinion)

```
value="{{ (isset($ap_paterno) ? $ap_paterno : '') }}"
```

Comment: How would you shorten the following when i want to check if Input:old: `@if(Input::old('ap_paterno')){{e(Input::old('ap_paterno'))}}@elseif(isset($ap_paterno)){{$ap_paterno}}@endif` ?

Comment: This is about the shortest it gets: `{{ (Input::old('ap_paterno') ? e(Input::old('ap_paterno')) : (isset($ap_paterno) ? $ap_paterno : '')) }}` I think that's pretty much the same length as yours though